# Unwanted popup storm triggered by old observeEvents created inside a function

Tags: r, shiny, observers, r-plotly

**How to stop observers created within a function from existing more than once when data changes?**

**UPDATE:** 
- Further simplified the app on github for easier testing.
- been trying to use `destroy`
**----**

I have made an app that requires several (10ish) versions of a plot throughout my program, and therefore I have written 2 functions:

- `myplotly` which creates the plots
- `mypopup` which creates the popups containing a pulseshape plot belonging to each particle in the `myplotly` plots, plus option buttons in the `modaldialog` popup, and the belonging observers

These dialogues are opened when the user clicks on a point in the first graph.

the shortened version of this function looks like this:

```
mypopup <- function(THEDATAFRAME, THEPLOT, THEGROUP, THEPULSEFRAME) {
..... bla bla lots more code in real app.....
  ..... one example of an observer with only 1 of the arguments needed for this one
  observeEvent(input[[paste("Close", THEPLOT, sep ='.')]], {
    removeModal()
  }, ignoreInit = T)

}
```

[image: pic]

The functions <sup>*1</sup> are called when the corresponding data frames are created or loaded and are called again when the data changes.

The problem I am facing is that after the data has been changed and the user clicks on a point the popup and all observers fire twice. If the data is changed again the pop-ups fire 3 times and so forth.
As well as that the popups based on the old data don't understand that there are now more than 1 cluster in the plot, so if you click cluster 2 or 3, error/ NA plots etc..

[image]

**Statements**:

- using **obs$destroy** might solve things, but not easy (see footnote <sup>*2</sup> )
- why do we get double observers in the first place? Fixing the symptoms is one thing, understanding why they are not simply overwritten is still a mystery to me.

I have created a stripped down example of the working code plus some files to run it on all of which can be found on the following github link:
https://github.com/madmark81/Observer-Madness

**footnotes**

<sup>1</sup> The reason why I have written it as functions it's because I apply this combination of plots and pop-ups several times in my main app each time depending on a unique combination of a base dataframe and a pulse dataframe as well as columns containing group ID and group name.

<sup>2</sup> 
Maximilian came up with the idea to use assigning observers to a variable. But implementation of this has to be done outside the mypopup function it seems and I haven't been able to get it to work on observers that use more than 1 input argument, which normally is sorted out by the 4 input arguments of the mypopup function, but can't be done using an lapply call as is done for the following example that only happens to have 1 input argument:

```
  lapply(plot.list, function(x){  
    o <- observeEvent(event_data("plotly_click", source = paste("plotlyplot", x, sep = '.')), {
      print('clicked')
      if(values[[paste("particle_viewer", x, sep = "_")]]) {
        ## when click in plot: Highlight the clicked particle with java, but also store the clicked point
        values[[paste("HLval", x, sep = "_")]] <- event_data("plotly_click", source = paste("plotlyplot", x, sep = '.'))  ## this code stores the last clicked point so that the point stays active when object is re-rendered
      }
    })
  })
```

followed by a destroy call every time the data is changed.

```
  observeEvent( values$TrainDFLogged,   {
    lapply(c("o"), function(x) {
          if (exists(x))
          {get(x)$destroy
            print('destroyed2')
          }
        })
  mypopup(values$TrainDFLogged, "SecondFile", "default", values$TrainPulses)
  })
```

**UPDATE 2**

When the observer is created OUTSIDE of the mypopup function code however, there is no need for the destroy and assigning to  'o' it seems, clicks are only observed on time I just found out. So perhaps we should simply find a way to create all the observers in an `lapply` or `mapply` style solution, but outside the `mypopup` code ?

Comment: I updated the github page as I found some small errors related to the stripping down from full app to "minimal" example for reproducing the problem, as well as a comma sep. issue with the data files. should function now to test the problem

Comment: One thing that jumps out from a quick glance is that there's a lot of output creation happening in observers, which often leads to nasty behavior. I can't look at this more until later, but I recommend watching these videos to help understand best practices using reactivity in Shiny - https://www.rstudio.com/resources/videos/effective-reactive-programming/

Comment: Thanks for looking into it greg, and also for the link. I have started watching it directly, I had seen it long before, but at that time my level was too low to follow it, and forgot all about it. 
I will take its knowledge to improve my app in general. 
In the mean time i'm also looking into a was to use something like plotlyproxyInvoke to update the data of the plots rather than rendering them again after the first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause was copies of the same `observeEvent` being created in a dynamic approach (`lapply` over x length)

The issue is that `Shiny` overwrite `ui` elements when they are rebuild (or at least only displays the newest version of it, but when you build numbered `observeEvents` to listen to a set of numbered buttons or such, it creates copies of each of those observers if you simply build them from i.e. 1:10 in a `lapply`.

the solution to prevent this problem is, is to record how many `observers` you made so far (max nr looped over), and then when the code associated with the loop updates, and requires a larger nr of `observers`, only make new ones for the nrs higher than the previous max.

in other words loop over 'previous maximum'+1 (which is 0 the first time) till new maximum, making sure there is only